# 301 Redirect in .htaccess is appending old file path/name to new url

Tags: .htaccess, append, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, absolute-path

I have two URLs: old-site.com and new-site.com.
My root folder on the old-site.com has NO FILES in it but only the .htaccess file. I don’t want to use the old domain anymore.  However, I do want to pass the link juice to the new domain.  Therefore, I created 301 Redirects in the .htaccess file and put it in the root folder on the old-site.com.

Why would the Redirect 301 append the “old-site.com/…” to the new-site.com?

My entire .htaccess looks like this (I skipped a few links to shorten it):

```
#Begin 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 / https://www.new-site.com/
Redirect 301 /contactus https://www.new-site/contact-us/
Redirect 301 /rentals https://www.new-site/lodging/
Redirect 301 /lift.html https://www.new-site/our-rentals/boat/
Redirect 301 /rentals.html https://www.new-site/our-rentals/
Redirect 301 /map.html https://www.new-site/contact-us/
Redirect 301 /giftshop https://www.new-site/store/gift-shop/
#End 301 Redirects
```

I don’t have any Rewrites.  The above is my entire code.

The following redirect works fine:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.new-site.com/
```

However, any other redirect creates the following absolute path on the new-site.com with a 404 error:

If I redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /contactus https://www.new-site/contact-us/
```

It goes to:

```
https://www.new-site.com/old-site.com/contactus
```

or

If I redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /lift.html https://www.new-site/lift/
```

It goes to:

```
https://www.new-site.com/old-site.com/lift.html
```

Why would the Redirect 301 append the “old-site.com/…” to the new-site.com?

Thank you,

Derek

Answer (score 2):

Your rules will not do what you need correct because of this line `Redirect 301 / https://www.new-site.com/` which will match any request first and if you put it in the last it will also match any request so , if you want it to match only root use `RedirectMatch` to be able to use regex like this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /?$ https://www.new-site.com/
```

By this the rest of rules will work as expected .

**Note:** clear browser cache the test

Comment: "you put it in the last it will also match any request" - But reversing the order of the directives would ordinarily be the solution here, since they no longer want to use the "old domain". However, this does not address why `old-site.com` is appearing in the URL-path of the target URL. But the regex `/?$` doesn't only redirect the homepage, it redirects _everything_! (And redirecting everything to the homepage on the new site - so you certainly would need to have changed the order of the directives anyway!) The regex should be `^/$` to redirect the homepage only.